# Filtering input fields in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to block a specific character and only allow string from a - z in react?
what I want is the user can only input a-z, and block others like [@,.-_] or even ' '(space).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
onChange={(e) => {
  let val = e.target.value

  val = val.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/ig, '')

  this.setState({
    value: val,
  })
}}
```

Comment: it should be `onChange= (e) => {
    let val = e.target.value
  
    val = val.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/ig, '')
  
    this.setState({
      inputValue: val,
    })
  }`

Answer (score 0):

We can use regx for filtering only alphanumeric values.

```
onChangeAlphaNumericInput(e) {
  const value = e.target.value;
  const regex = /[^A-Za-z]/ig; //this will admit letters, numbers and dashes
  if (value.match(regex) || value === "") {
    this.setState({ inputValue: value });
  }
}
```

Comment: but, it still allows '-'